# Email Campaign Preview Image is Blank

Tags: ecm

Whenever we deploy a Email Campaign and then open it from the Dashboard the Email Campaign Preview Image is Blank.

Checked PhantomJS location is correct. Also checked the temp/screenshot folder and we see the image LJw$TQ-en-1-gA7hbw--0---0x0.png in there but when we open it , its a blank image.

```
<img src="/temp/screenshots/LJw$TQ-en-1-gA7hbw--0---0x0.png" data-sc-id="MessagePreviewImage" class="sc-image sc_Image_724 data-sc-registered sc-emailpreview" data-bind="visible:isVisible, attr: {src: src, alt: alt}" data-sc-require="/-/speak/v1/business/image.js" data-image-src="/sitecore/images/blank.gif">
```

There is no Javascript error in the console.But we do the the following error in the log file
[image]
PhantomJS error:
SetProcessDpiAwareness failed: "COM error 0x80070005 (Unknown error 0x0ffffffff80070005)"

Comment: do you have basic authentication enabled?

Comment: we do not have basic authentication added in that environment. But on my local when on my local when this works I have basic authentication set to disabled.

Comment: @Renuka you have to check IP white listing if applied any I had same issue

Comment: @NikhilKulkarni not sure what IP I should be testing. I mean we have only one CM server. Also its working on all our lower environment, the issue is on just the Prod server

Comment: @Renuka is your solution is on Azure PaaS?(here IP means IP of CM and CD app-services.), if yes then go to App service-->Networking-->Access Restrictions here you will find the that if anything (IP's) configured or not specifically check your CD service. Because CM renders website to take the screenshots and it gets saved in temp folder you can also cross verify if those are created there.once you check this I can help further.

Comment: @NikhilKulkarni we are not on Azure PaaS we have one server which is standalone and has both CM and CD

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful for someone who's facing this issue.

I faced this same problem but when I was running the A/B Testing, where the images were blank, such as the picture below:

[image]

**1)** First, check if you're generating screenshot images at `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<your-site>\temp\screenshots`. If not, there is some issue related to the `ContentTesting.PhantomJS.ExecutablePath` parameter or some security policy blocking the PhantomJS to create the Screenshot. Check the security policy for the this folder  and for `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\<your-site>\App_Data\tools\phantomjs`

[image]

**2)** Then, I noticed that the images were being generated but some of them were blanked. After a long investigation, I figured out that this issue was related to the `ContentTesting.PhantomJS.SSLProtocol` within the `Sitecore.ContentTesting.config`. It was set up with "**any**", then I changed it to "**TLSv1**" and it worked fine. Somehow, there's a config in our server only accepting this type of protocol. Also, if it doesn't work for you, try other options like "**SSLv2**", and "**SSLv3**".

[image]

**3)** In addition, after changing this config, clean the browser cache/cookies and remove all files from the ...\temp\screencshoots folder.

Hope it helps you!